# Can I execute a function after setState is finished updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am very new to ReactJS (as in, just started today).  I don't quite understand how `setState` works.  I am combining React and Easel JS to draw a grid based on user input.  Here is my JS bin:
http://jsbin.com/zatula/edit?js,output

Here is the code:

```
    var stage;
   
    var Grid = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {
                rows: 10,
                cols: 10
            }
        },
        componentDidMount: function () {
            this.drawGrid();
        },
        drawGrid: function() {
            stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
            var rectangles = [];
            var rectangle;
            //Rows
            for (var x = 0; x < this.state.rows; x++)
            {
                // Columns
                for (var y = 0; y < this.state.cols; y++)
                {
                    var color = "Green";
                    rectangle = new createjs.Shape();
                    rectangle.graphics.beginFill(color);
                    rectangle.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 44);
                    rectangle.x = x * 33;
                    rectangle.y = y * 45;

                    stage.addChild(rectangle);

                    var id = rectangle.x + "_" + rectangle.y;
                    rectangles[id] = rectangle;
                }
            }
            stage.update();
        },
        updateNumRows: function(event) {
            this.setState({ rows: event.target.value });
            this.drawGrid();
        },
        updateNumCols: function(event) {
            this.setState({ cols: event.target.value });
            this.drawGrid();
        },
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="canvas-wrapper">
                        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="500"></canvas>
                        <p>Rows: { this.state.rows }</p>
                        <p>Columns: {this.state.cols }</p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="array-form">
                        <form>
                            <label>Number of Rows</label>
                            <select id="numRows" value={this.state.rows} onChange={ this.updateNumRows }>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value ="5">5</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                            </select>
                            <label>Number of Columns</label>
                            <select id="numCols" value={this.state.cols} onChange={ this.updateNumCols }>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="12">12</option>
                                <option value="15">15</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                            </select>
                        </form>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Grid />,
        document.getElementById("container")
    );
```

You can see in the JSbin when you change the number of rows or columns with one of the dropdowns, nothing will happen the first time.  The next time you change a dropdown value, the grid will draw to the previous state's row and column values.  I am guessing this is happening because my `this.drawGrid()` function is executing before `setState` is complete.  Maybe there is another reason?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 633, accepted):

`setState(updater[, callback])` is an async function:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

You can execute a function after setState is finishing using the second param `callback` like:

```
this.setState({
    someState: obj
}, () => {
    this.afterSetStateFinished();
});
```

The same can be done with hooks in React functional component:

https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback#usage

Look at useStateWithCallbackLazy:

```
import { useStateWithCallbackLazy } from 'use-state-with-callback';

const [count, setCount] = useStateWithCallbackLazy(0);

setCount(count + 1, () => {
   afterSetCountFinished();
});
```

Comment: or just 
this.setState({
    someState: obj
}, 
    this.afterSetStateFinished
);

Comment: The lovely feature that the setter function of  `useState`  hook doesn't have it and we should use `useEffect` and many dirty codes to settle it.

Comment: Sadly if you try to use this solution with Hooks, you will get this error:  




`index.js:1451 Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().`

Comment: @Des can you write your issue here: https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback/issues and share the source code. Are you sure that you use useStateWithCallbackLazy Hook?

Comment: @sytolk I'm sorry. I was so tired when I was looking for a solution to this that my mind just skipped that part. My comment is for regular useState. That's my bad.

Comment: I checked this hook. Interesting. As React batches `setState` updates, how does this hook behave in cases when multiple `setStates` are called? I suspect that the latest callback will just override the previous one.

Answer (score 30):

`render` will be called every time you `setState` to re-render the component if there are changes. If you move your call to `drawGrid` there rather than calling it in your `update*` methods, you shouldn't have a problem.

If that doesn't work for you, there is also an overload of `setState` that takes a callback as a second parameter. You should be able to take advantage of that as a last resort.

Comment: Thank you - your first suggestion works and (mostly) makes sense.  I did this:  `render: function() { this.drawGrid(); return......`

Comment: Ahem, please don't do this in `render()`... sytolk's answer should be the accepted one

Comment: This is a wrong answer, setState will go for infintie loop and will crash the page.

Comment: Justin, I"m interested in why said the callback of `setState` should be used a last resort.  I agree with most people here that it makes sense to use that approach.

Comment: @mfeineis why not do this in render?

Comment: @Rohmer this is way to expensive to execute on every render call while it's obviously not needed on every call either. If it was pure `react` the vdom would take care of not doing too much work in most cases, this is interop with another library you want to minimize

Answer (score 20):

### Making `setState` return a `Promise`

In addition to passing a `callback` to `setState()` method, you can wrap it around an `async` function and use the `then()` method -- which in some cases might produce a cleaner code:

```
(async () => new Promise(resolve => this.setState({dummy: true}), resolve)()
    .then(() => { console.log('state:', this.state) });
```

And here you can take this one more step ahead and make a reusable `setState` function that in my opinion is better than the above version:

```
const promiseState = async state =>
    new Promise(resolve => this.setState(state, resolve));

promiseState({...})
    .then(() => promiseState({...})
    .then(() => {
        ...  // other code
        return promiseState({...});
    })
    .then(() => {...});
```

This works fine in *React* 16.4, but I haven't tested it in earlier versions of *React* yet.

Also worth mentioning that keeping your *callback* code in `componentDidUpdate` method is a better practice in most -- probably all, cases.

Comment: how to do for functional component?

Answer (score 19):

With hooks in React 16.8 onward, it's easy to do this with `useEffect`

I've created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-wu-rtgbg?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate this.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // code to be run when state variables in
  // dependency array changes
}, [stateVariables, thatShould, triggerChange])
```

Basically, `useEffect` synchronises with state changes and this can be used to render the  canvas

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Stage, Shape } from "@createjs/easeljs";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(10);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(10);
  let stage = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    stage.current = new Stage("canvas");
    var rectangles = [];
    var rectangle;
    //Rows
    for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
      // Columns
      for (var y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
        var color = "Green";
        rectangle = new Shape();
        rectangle.graphics.beginFill(color);
        rectangle.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 32, 44);
        rectangle.x = y * 33;
        rectangle.y = x * 45;

        stage.current.addChild(rectangle);

        var id = rectangle.x + "_" + rectangle.y;
        rectangles[id] = rectangle;
      }
    }
    stage.current.update();
  }, [rows, columns]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="canvas-wrapper">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
        <p>Rows: {rows}</p>
        <p>Columns: {columns}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="array-form">
        <form>
          <label>Number of Rows</label>
          <select
            id="numRows"
            value={rows}
            onChange={(e) => setRows(e.target.value)}
          >
            {getOptions()}
          </select>
          <label>Number of Columns</label>
          <select
            id="numCols"
            value={columns}
            onChange={(e) => setColumns(e.target.value)}
          >
            {getOptions()}
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const getOptions = () => {
  const options = [1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 15, 20];
  return (
    <>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <option key={option} value={option}>
          {option}
        </option>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. useEffect should not be used for this. Pls, don't do this

Answer (score 12):

when new props or states being received (like you call `setState` here), React will invoked some functions, which are called `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate`

in your case, just simply add a `componentDidUpdate` function to call `this.drawGrid()`

here is working code in [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/setofirenu/edit?html,js,output)

as I mentioned, in the code, `componentDidUpdate` will be invoked after `this.setState(...)`

then `componentDidUpdate` inside is going to call `this.drawGrid()`

read more about component **Lifecycle** in React https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate

Comment: instead of just pasting the link. please add the relevant portions in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had to run some function after updating the state and not on every update of state.
My scenario:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
        matrix: Array(9).fill(null),
        xIsNext: true,
    });

...
...

setState({
    matrix: squares,
    xIsNext: !state.xIsNext,
})
sendUpdatedStateToServer(state);
```

Here `sendUpdatedStateToServer()` is the required function to run after updating the state.
I didn't want to use useEffect() as I do not want to run `sendUpdatedStateToServer()` after every state updates.

What worked for me:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
        matrix: Array(9).fill(null),
        xIsNext: true,
    });

...
...
const newObj = {
    matrix: squares,
    xIsNext: !state.xIsNext,
}
setState(newObj);
sendUpdatedStateToServer(newObj);
```

I just created a new object which is required by the function to run after the state updates and and simply used it. Here the setState function will keep on updating the state and the `sendUpdatedStateToServer()` will receive the updated state, which is what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is approached by a class component since the new recommended way of creating components is by functions, this answer addresses the problem from the functional hooks that react introduced on React v16

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => console.log(count), [count]);
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{count}</span>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click Me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

as you can see in this example this is a simple counter component. but the `useEffect` hook of this example has a second argument as an array of dependencies (a dependent state that it might rely on). so the hook **only** runs if the `count` is updated. when an empty array is passed, `useEffect` runs only once since there are no dependent state variables for it to listen to. 
A simple but an effective guide to react hooks - [10 React Hooks Explained | Fireship](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNhaISOUy6Q)

Answer (score 0):

React.useEffect() hook is not called when setState() method is invoked with same value(as the current one). Hence as a workaround, another state variable is used to manually retrigger the callback.

Note: This is useful when your callback is resolving a promise or something and you have to call it after the state update(even if UI stays the same).

```
import * as React from "react";

const randomString = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);

const useStateWithCallbackLazy = (initialValue) => {
  const callbackRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    value: initialValue,
    revision: randomString(),
  });

  /**
   *  React.useEffect() hook is not called when setState() method is invoked with same value(as the current one)
   *  Hence as a workaround, another state variable is used to manually retrigger the callback
   *  Note: This is useful when your callback is resolving a promise or something and you have to call it after the state update(even if UI stays the same)
   */
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (callbackRef.current) {
      callbackRef.current(state.value);

      callbackRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [state.revision, state.value]);

  const setValueWithCallback = React.useCallback((newValue, callback) => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;

    return setState({
      value: newValue,
      // Note: even if newValue is same as the previous value, this random string will re-trigger useEffect()
      // This is intentional
      revision: randomString(),
    });
  }, []);

  return [state.value, setValueWithCallback];
};
```

Usage:

```
const [count, setCount] = useStateWithCallbackLazy(0);

setCount(count + 1, () => {
   afterSetCountFinished();
});
```

Comment: What is better? and if you think its better why not make a PR here: https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback/pulls for me this think with revision is overhead

Comment: I agree with you but isnt the hook supposed to call the callback once the state is updated (even if there are no visual changes). In my case that was crucial as the callback itself was resolving a promise.

Comment: Simple you can try to check if state is changed before update state and rerender component: `if(oldState !== newValue) setState(newValue)` gennerally it sounds like wrong architecture and lack of [performance](https://felixgerschau.com/react-performance-react-memo/#solving-this-with-areequal)

Comment: If you need to force update functional component this is the oficial React recomendation for this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's an old question. Still providing my solution, which just works and easy to understand. It's also type safe and uses no random generator. Necessary memorizations are implemented so that unnecessary re-renders can be avoided:

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useCallback, useMemo } from "react"

const useStateWithCallback = <T,>(value: T) => {
  const callbackRef = useRef<T => void>();
  // As we know, re-created object with exact same value
  // resides in different memory location.
  // We are storing the set value inside an object,
  // so that the hook re-renders everytime the setState is called
  // even with the same value.
  const [state, setState] = useState({ value });

  // Anytime setState is called and the value is updated,
  // React will very soon call this effect
  // It will call the callback, if any,
  // then clear it as we want to run the callback once.
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current?.(state.value)
    callbackRef.current = undefined
  }, [state]);

  // We are momoizing the function so that the hook doesn't
  // re-render unnecessarily
  const setStateWithCallback = useCallback((value: T, callback: T => void) => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
    setState({ value });
  }, []);

  // Finally we return the tuple in React useState like format,
  // without SetStateAction type. Also, we memoize,
  // so that the component using the hook only re-renders
  // on value change, not on each update.
  // In another word, the original useState behaviour is preserved.
  return useMemo(() =>
    [state.value, setStateWithCallback] as const,
    [state.value, setStateWithCallback]
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
const [value, setValue] = useStateWithCallback('whatever');

setValue('whatever', (value) => {
   console.info(value);
   doWhateverIWant();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For this issue I prefer to use `useEffect`

```
const MyComponent: FC = () => {
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0); 
 const ref = useRef(false)

 const handeIncreaseCount = () => {
  setCount(count => count + 1)
  ref.current = true;
 }

 useEffect(() => {
   if(ref.current) {
     // here your state is updated so you can perform your action that you want to be executed  
     ref.current = flase;
   }
 }, [count])

 return (
    ...
     <button onClick={() => handeIncreaseCount()}>Increment</button>
    ...
 )
}
```

The problem of using `setState` call backs, is that you are causing double re-renders that may affect negatively your app performance

Comment: This will not work, because effects are run only when there is a change. We want to run a callback anytime setState is called, even if there is no change. Also, pre-mature optimization is evil. If we must do something, it should be done. If one additional render messes up your app, then there is something wrong elsewhere