# How to get data using two different state variables in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made 4 radio buttons and one input box for option:other radio button(see screenshot). When I check other radio button and enter the value in input box then `this.state.gender` becomes `-1` and `this.state.gendertext` equals to the text entered in input box. So I want to do `this.state.gender = this.state.gendertext` if and only if other radio button is checked otherwise `this.state.gender` equals to radio button option value and `this.state.gendertext = ''`

Note: -1 is used as an identifier for last radio button option.

contactform.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ContactForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        gender:'',
      gendertext:''

    };
  }

setGender(checkedValue){
    console.log(checkedValue);
    this.setState({
        gender:checkedValue
    })
  }

  onChangeTextBoxGender(event){
  this.setState({gendertext: event.target.value})
  }

savedata(age, gender, health, name, email, info, fitness){
        let newcontent = contentref.push();

      if(this.state.gender === -1){
        this.setState({
          gender:this.state.gendertext
        })
      }

        newcontent.set({

            gender:this.state.gender,
        gendertext:this.state.gendertext

        });
  }
 render() {

    return (
      <div>

        <div id="center">
          <form>
<div id="gender">
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <h4>What is your gender?</h4>  
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" checked={(this.state.gender === 'Female')} onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,'Female')}/> Female</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" checked={(this.state.gender === 'Male')} onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,'Male')}/> Male</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" checked={(this.state.gender === 'Prefer not to say')} onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,'Prefer not to say')}/> Prefer not to say</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <div className="radio">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="gender" checked={(this.state.gender === -1)} onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,-1)}/>Other</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-inline" id="other1" value={this.state.gendertext} onChange={this.onChangeTextBoxGender.bind(this)}/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
 </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContactForm;
```

Screenshot:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKQc1.png)

Comment: what is the issue that you are facing ?

Comment: @ViswasMenon I have made 2 state variables gender and gendertext when I check option radio button `this.state.gender` becomes -1 and as we have checked other radio button we type in text in input button so now `this.state.gendertext` equals input box text. Now if `this.state.gender === -1` I want it to be equal to `this.state.gendertext`

Comment: Arent you doing that check inside savedata() above, or is it not working ?

Comment: I'm also unclear of what your question is. seems very [x-y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ish to me. if you want to change state call setState. but really I think you should describe what the functionality should be, not what you think your solution should be

Comment: also what is `contentref` ? looks undefined to me

Comment: @ViswasMenon No the if statement is not working inside savedata

Comment: are you not getting errors in the console?

Comment: @azium I am pushing my data to firebase but the question is not related to that.

Comment: @azium I have made 2 state variables gender and gendertext when I check option radio button this.state.gender becomes -1 and as we have checked other radio button we type in text in input button so now `this.state.gendertext` equals input box text. Now if` this.state.gender === -1` I want it to be equal to `this.state.gendertext`

Comment: so call setState in your onChange handler?

Comment: @azium I want  content of `this.state.gender` to be equal to `this.state.gendertext` only if the other radio button is checked else `this.state.gender` is equal to value of radio button option.

Comment: right..... so call setState! if you want to change state, then you have to call setState

Comment: @azium Did you got what I am trying to do.

Comment: @azium I cannot understand how an where to setState ?

Comment: in this function `this.onChangeTextBoxGender`

Comment: @azium Does not work

Comment: it should can you post what you tried? (update your question with new code)

Comment: @azium See me entire code https://jsfiddle.net/5L02k7zz/

Comment: @azium Have you checked out the code in jsfiddle

Comment: @fire-man, what does do this piece of code?

 `newcontent.set`

Comment: @salman.zare I am pushing data to database firebase it has nothing to do with the question. It just gets pushed when submit button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  onChangeTextBoxGender(event){
    const txt=event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      gendertext: txt,
        gender: txt
    })
  }
```

And,

```
  setGender(checkedValue){
    console.log(checkedValue);
    this.setState({
      gender:checkedValue,
      gendertext:''
    })
  }
```

And change the following line:

`<label><input type="radio" name="gender" checked={(this.state.gender === -1 || this.state.gendertext.length >0)} onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,-1)}/>Other</label>`

Comment: what?? are you saying you can only have one key on state?

Comment: @azium, what's the issue?!

Comment: @salman.zare Your answer is not working I have made 2 state variables gender and gendertext when I check option radio button this.state.gender becomes -1 and as we have checked other radio button we type in text in input button so now this.state.gendertext equals input box text. Now if` this.state.gender === -1` I want it to be equal to this.state.gendertext

Comment: Inside the `savedata ` function.

Comment: @salman.zare I am getting error expected please see my edited code here https://jsfiddle.net/5L02k7zz/

Comment: ok, change your `onChangeTextBoxGender` and `setGender` functions like above updated code.

Comment: @salman.zare When I click on radio button other and then when I start typing in input box other radio button gets unchecked why is this happening. It is not working why ?

Comment: Change the following line:

` <label><input type="radio" name="gender" checked={(this.state.gender === -1 || this.state.gendertext.length >0)} onChange={this.setGender.bind(this,-1)}/>Other</label>`

Comment: @salman.zare Why have you used function to setState part in your answer

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687091/can-i-execute-a-function-after-setstate-is-finished-updating

Comment: @salman.zare I could not understand why did you used function to setState in `onChangeTextBoxGender`

Comment: @salman.zare What if we setState of `gender: txt` inside setState without callback will it work?

Comment: You right, I updated the code. Initially I used this one for first update the state and then doing another action. But with new changes we don't need it.
I update the above code.

Comment: @salman.zare Can you explain why have you added this line `this.state.gendertext.length >0`

Comment: Because we are assigning the `gendertext` to the 'gender', and we need to check if the text is not empty then `checked` the radioButton.