# React - setState does not update the value

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update the state with a localStorage value in DidMount, but it is not updating:

```
type Props = {
};

type State = {
    id_evaluation: string,
};

class Evaluation extends Component < Props, State > {
    state = {
        id_evaluation: '',
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const id_eval = getEvaluation();
        console.log('1 - ', id_eval)

        this.setState({
            id_evaluation: '1',
        });

        console.log('2 - ', this.state.id_evaluation)
```

In the first console.log I have the value 1, in the second it remains empty, it does not update the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.setState is an async function.

```
 this.setState({
        id_evaluation: '1',
 }, () => console.log('2 - ', this.state.id_evaluation));
```

Callback function would solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you call console.log before the state has updated. Try this:

```
this.setState({
  id_evaluation: '1',
}, () => {
  console.log('2 - ', this.state.id_evaluation);
});
```

See this thread:

[Can I execute a function after setState is finished updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687091/can-i-execute-a-function-after-setstate-is-finished-updating)

Answer (score 2):

`setState` works asynchronously so pass `console.log` as `callback` to get updated state.

```
this.setState({ id_evaluation: '1'}, () => console.log('2- ', this.state.id_evaluation));
```

when used as your code, `console.log('2 - ', this.state.id_evaluation)` is printing previous state not the updated state.