# How to Run functions synchronously in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios, synchronous

I'm new to JavaScript and React and am trying to move away from tutorials so have started making a simple app for my own learning benefit but have run into a roadblock with functions running asynchronously.

In `onSearchSubmit`, there is a `setState` which has the following in its callback:

```
this.findSalaryRangeMin(data.advertiser.id, data.teaser);
this.findSalaryRangeMax(data.advertiser.id, data.teaser);
```

How can I get these two functions above to run synchronously? `findSalaryRangeMax` uses `this.state.salaryLower` which is set in `findSalaryRangeMin`, but the `console.log` below reveals that `findSalaryRangeMax` is firing before `findSalaryRangeMin` has completed.

```
  findSalaryRangeMax = (advertiserId, teaser) => {
    console.log(`this.state.salaryLower: `, this.state.salaryLower);
    // ... More code
  };
```

I've read some resources which mention using promises, but I wasn't able to figure out how to apply it... I also am wondering whether it can be achieved with `async`/`await`.

**Full(ish) Code:**
(I've removed some code for simplicity)

```js
import React from "react";
import JobSearch from "../api/jobSearch"; // axios
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    jobTitle: "",
    advertiser: "",
    salaryLower: "",
    salaryLowerTop: "",
    salaryUpper: "",
    salaryUpperTop: ""
  };

  findSalaryRangeMin = (advertiserId, teaser) => {
    this.setState({ salaryLower: 0, salaryLowerTop: 200000 }, async () => {
      let salaryLowerPrev;
      for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        const response = await JobSearch.get(
          `http://localhost:3001/salary-range/${advertiserId}/${this.state.salaryLower}/${this.state.salaryLowerTop}/${teaser}`
        );
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.totalCount === 1) {
          salaryLowerPrev = this.state.salaryLowerTop;
          this.setState({
            salaryLowerTop: Math.round(
              (this.state.salaryLowerTop - this.state.salaryLower) / 2 +
                this.state.salaryLower
            )
          });
        } else {
          this.setState(
            {
              salaryLowerTop: salaryLowerPrev
            },
            () => {
              this.setState({
                salaryLower: Math.round(
                  (this.state.salaryLowerTop - this.state.salaryLower) / 2 +
                    this.state.salaryLower
                )
              });
            }
          );
        }
      }
    });
  };

  findSalaryRangeMax = (advertiserId, teaser) => {
    console.log(`this.state.salaryLower: `, this.state.salaryLower);
    // ... More code
  };

  onSearchSubmit = async term => {
    const response = await JobSearch.get(
      `http://localhost:3001/job-info/${term}`
    );
    if (response.data.totalCount === 1) {
      const data = response.data.data[0];
      this.setState(
        {
          jobTitle: data.title,
          advertiser: data.advertiser.description
        },
        () => {
          this.findSalaryRangeMin(data.advertiser.id, data.teaser);
          this.findSalaryRangeMax(data.advertiser.id, data.teaser);
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.log("totalCount not equal to 1: ", response.data.totalCount);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar onSearchSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
        <hr />
        <div>
          Job Title: {this.state.jobTitle}
          Advertiser: {this.state.advertiser}
          Salary Lower Range: {this.state.salaryLower}
          Salary Upper Range: {this.state.salaryUpper}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

To give some context, the app I'm trying to make, queries an API for a jobs listing site. The API response doesn't reveal a salary range for an individual job, but the salary can fairly accurately be determined by querying salary ranges.

Comment: @Dupocas Thanks for the quick reply + link. I understand it's the same concept, but I was hoping for a more JS specific context

Comment: What do you mean by "js specific context" ?

Comment: Something in JavaScript. The accepted answer for that linked question is in a C# context. Trying to learn a new concept is hard enough, let alone having it explained in a programming language I don't know anything about.

Comment: Wow. That was my bad actually. I messed up the links (sorry about that): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512388/understanding-async-await-on-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding that async or promises are needed if you want the functions to run synchronously and the existing code will run to the following line `findSalaryRangeMax` before returning with the data needed.

async/await and promises will definitely help, but often it's worth considering a few code changes too. As an example, you could combine the two functions into a single function like

```
findSalaryRanges(data.advertiser.id, data.teaser)
```

and fetch the data, process and set state once.

some pseudo code:

```
findSalaryRanges = async () => {
    // get all the data needed first
    const maxSalaryData = await JobSearch.get(`http://localhost:3001/salary-range/${advertiserId}/${this.state.salaryLower}/${this.state.salaryLowerTop}/${teaser}`);
    const minSalaryData = await JobSearch.get(...);

    // process data as needed
    ...

    // set state once
    this.setState({
        salaryTop: salaryTop,
        salaryLower: salaryLower
    });
};
```

Comment: I ended up giving the code a complete overhaul. I couldn't do it quite the way that you proposed as my application requires to compare API results and submit another query based on result, but it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: No prob, sometimes you just need a sanity check to help you get a few ideas

Answer (score 0):

setState is async, so if you are dependent on the value of the state before running the next function you could do something like:

```
this.setState({
  salaryLowerTop: Math.round(
    (this.state.salaryLowerTop - this.state.salaryLower) / 2 +
      this.state.salaryLower
    )
}, () => this.findSalaryRangeMax(data.advertiser.id, data.teaser))
```

[Can I execute a function after setState is finished updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687091/can-i-execute-a-function-after-setstate-is-finished-updating)

Comment: I've tried using `.then()`, but I get the following error when I use it: `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: I've edited my answer, it's been a while since I've worked w/ class components :)