# ReactJS - passing part of onClick function as a prop from parent component

Tags: reactjs

Hey guys I am trying to pass a command in a prop to child component from a parent. The thing is that after my button is clicked a state in parent component has to be changed for intended sidebar to open. I seem to not get it right with the .then() part at the end on the onClick function, as I get error: ×
*Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined*

**CHILD COMPONENT:**

```
return (
          <div
            className="results-item"
            onClick={async () => {
              let place_detail;
              try {
                const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${places.place_id}&fields=name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=
      MYAPIKEY`;
                const response = await axios.get(URL);
                console.log(response.data);
                place_detail = response.data.results;
              } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
              }

              this.setState({ place_detail }).then(this.props.sideBarOpen);
            }}
          >
            <ResultsItem
              name={places.name}
              image={Thumbnail}
              rating={places.rating}
              rating_total={places.user_ratings_total}
            />
          </div>
        );
```

**PARENT COMPONENT:**

```
<Search sideBarOpen={() => setOpen(!open)} />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I execute a function after setState is finished updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687091/can-i-execute-a-function-after-setstate-is-finished-updating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` doesn't return a promise. Use a callback instead:

```
this.setState({ place_detail }, () => {
   this.props.sideBarOpen();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.then` on `setState` call. You can use callback function of setState to what you are trying to do -

```
this.setState({ place_detail }, () => this.props.sideBarOpen());
```