# ReactJS: setState() value is rendering in console.log but not updating in state

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Here I am getting small issue with `setState()` . I know this `setState()` is an `asynchronous` function. I have gone some example from [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/setstate-doesnt-update-the-state-immediately) as well and I am getting my value in `console.log()` but this same is not updating in state.

What should I need to change here to get the updated `state()` value. Any suggestion for me please.

Here in my code on tab change the `state` value should be updated for `form` submission.

//Code

```
handleOnSubmitJoinUS(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name,  phone, email, comment, activeTab } = this.state;

    if (activeTab == 0 ) {

        this.setState({comment: "Message for : Becoming a team member"}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.comment);
        });

    } else if (activeTab == 1) {
        this.setState({comment: "Message for : Becoming a Vendor Partner"}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.comment);
        });

    } else {
        this.setState({comment: "Message for : Becoming a Designer Associates"}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.comment);
        });
    }
    
    
    const sendingMsgData = {
        name,  phone, email, comment
    }

    //attempt to login
    if (sendingMsgData.email && sendingMsgData.name && sendingMsgData.phone  != null  ) {
        this.setState({msg : "Thank you! we recieved your submission successfully, we will surely contact you within 24 hours"});
        window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()}, 1000);
    } 
    this.props.sendingConsultation(sendingMsgData);
    
}
```

Comment: try this callback instead of window.setTimeout https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186956/9277453

Comment: You should put attempt to login code in setState callback functions where you console.log the values. Otherwise your attempt to login code will run before updating the values.

Comment: @AlexNikonov thank you for your time. sure I will chekc this as well.

Comment: @ÇağataySel thank you . sure I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `setState` is asynchronous, so the rest of the function continues running, doing all that message sending and so on before the state is actually set in `this.state`. For your original code, that'd mean the rest of the code should be in that post-setState callback.

However, it doesn't look like `comment` needs to be in the state at all, since you're deriving it from `state.activeTab`:

```
handleOnSubmitJoinUS(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { name, phone, email, activeTab } = this.state;
  let comment;

  if (activeTab == 0) {
    comment = "Message for : Becoming a team member";
  } else if (activeTab == 1) {
    comment = "Message for : Becoming a Vendor Partner";
  } else {
    comment = "Message for : Becoming a Designer Associates";
  }

  const sendingMsgData = {
    name,
    phone,
    email,
    comment,
  };

  //attempt to login
  if (sendingMsgData.email && sendingMsgData.name && sendingMsgData.phone != null) {
    this.setState({ msg: "Thank you! we recieved your submission successfully, we will surely contact you within 24 hours" });
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      window.location.reload();
    }, 1000);
  }
  this.props.sendingConsultation(sendingMsgData);
}
```

If you do really need it in `state` for some reason, you can do a `this.setState({comment})` at the end.

Comment: Ohhh @AKX thank you so much. I got your point. thank you.