# Execute a function after setState is finished updating inside functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to execute a function after functional component setstate has been completed.
There are two ideas where we can use to know the state update has been completed

- Using useEffect
- [use-state-with-callback](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback) (But the callback is not called as expected.)

We can use useEffect to do a correct approach. But we cannot use in all the situation.
For example

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const func1 = ()=>{}
const func2 = ()=>{}
const func3 = ()=>{}
```

The setCount has been called inside func1 and func3.
After setCount in func1, I need to call func2 but not in func3.
If I use useEffect, whenever count has been updated the func2 will be called.

So I need a proper callback which need to be called after setState.

[Can I execute a function after setState is finished updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687091/can-i-execute-a-function-after-setstate-is-finished-updating)

Comment: You have to call func2 only after setState has happened in func 1? is this your question?

Comment: Yes, that is my question. But the setState can be done in func3 too

Comment: so, is there a need to do setState in func1

Comment: Yes, the need is in both func1 and func3. But only after setState in func1, then func2 should be called. I hope you understood the question and will not ask the same question further

Comment: One last question are you calling function2 in function1

Comment: Please read your first comment.

Answer (score -1):

With function components, you need to think in terms of a state machine. Your component function is called when state changes, and if you want to perform a side effect as a result of rendering that state, as you said you use `useEffect`. The key is to ensure that your state tells you what you need to do.

It sounds like you need a second state item that tells you whether to call `func2`. Very roughly:

```
function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [doTheCall, setDoTheCall] = useState(false);

    const func1 = () => {
        setCount((count) => {
            const value = /*...*/;
            setDoTheCall(true); // Indicate the call should be done
            return value;
        });
    };

    const func2 = () => {
        // ...
    }

    const func3 = () => {
        setCount(/*...*/);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // Do the call if we're supposed to
        if (doTheCall) {
            func2();
            setDoTheCall(false);
        }
    }, [doTheCall]);

    // ...
}
```

There I've used a simple flag, but another approach is to set the same value you're setting for `count`:

```
function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [countForCall, setCountForCall] = useState(false);

    const func1 = () => {
        setCount((count) => {
            const value = /*...*/;
            setCountForCall(value); // Set the value we compare with `count`
            return value;
        });
    };

    const func2 = () => {
        // ...
    }

    const func3 = () => {
        setCount(/*...*/);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        // Do the call if we're supposed to
        if (count === countForCall) {
            func2();
            setCountForCall({}); // Will never match `count`
        }
    }, [count, countForCall]);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought to use the same. But this push me to write additional codes unwantedly . So, I want to check is there any alternate approach is available.

Comment: @JeevanandanJ - You can write your own hook to do this, then reuse it.

Comment: added custom hook. Please refer that