# How to pass updated set State value in axios request as params

Tags: mysql, react-native, react-hooks, axios, asyncstorage

I'm a beginner in react native, I'm trying to get user information from mysql database through an axios API get request.

Once logged in, I stored email address in AsyncStorage and later want to use that email address from AsyncStorage as params or parameters to get the user details.

I wrote a code which set initial state of the setState as 'na'. Please help me how I can pass the email address from AsyncStorage as params or parameters.

Here is my code.

```
// to load email address
  const [SessionEmail, setSessionEmail] = useState('na');
```

```
// to load users info
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

```
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {   
      getUsername();
      getUsersInfoFromAPI();
    }, [])
  );
```

```
// to get the session username from localstorage
  const getUsername = async () => {
    try {
      const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Username')
      if (username !== null) {
        setSessionEmail(username);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

```
 // API Calling user details
  const getUsersInfoFromAPI = async () => {
    await axios.get(`https://myapi.co.in/api/user/?email=${SessionEmail}`)
      .then(response => {
        setUser(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

After the page is rendered, and I load page from metro, I can see the parameters have been sent to server.

Comment: Have you tried in this way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45186956

Comment: @YakupMalikov Well, yes I tried that but it is on button click. However, here I'm trying to send updated set state value in axios parameters to get details based on that parameters. 

I'm new to react, my backend is mysql. Hence, for where clause I need username sent to  API which is PHP.

Once API gets username it fetch user details. setState did get updated with asyncstorage value but not passed into axios parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code in this way:

```
useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {   
      getUsername();
    }, [])
  );
```

Instead of saving your email to state, sent it to function directly but if you are using it for other reason you can still save it but call function while getting username from AsyncStorage with username parameter like below.

```
// to get the session username from localstorage
  const getUsername = async () => {
    try {
      const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Username')
      if (username !== null) {
        getUsersInfoFromAPI(username);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

```
// API Calling user details
  const getUsersInfoFromAPI = async (email) => {
    await axios.get(`https://myapi.co.in/api/user/?email=${email}`)
      .then(response => {
        setUser(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I'm able to send AsyncStorage value to API. I really appreciate your efforts and help.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

here you can use like this

```
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Yes, I did make changes to it. Initial value I set as na.


  const [users, setUsers] = useState('na');

Comment: you can also use as () blank it's working or not ?

Comment: No it's not working, value is not being sent to params.

    await axios.get(`https://myapi.co.in/api/user/?email=${SessionEmail}`)

But it get's rendered and displayed in textview

When I save the page from VSC, it's sends in params