# Code missing second letter of string while typing it out

Tags: javascript

I'm building a web application and have a function that types out letters one by one for effect, at 100ms intervals. However it's skipping the second letter of the string I'm trying to have it type.

It works if I prepend two spaces at the beginning of the string, but I have no idea why.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let message = 'This is not working';
  let initialIndex = 0;
  setText('');

  const typingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (initialIndex < message.length-1) {
      setText((prevText) => prevText + message[initialIndex]);
      initialIndex++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(typingInterval);
    }
  }, 100);
```

Comment: Please post the complete code of the `useEffect` call, in particular the cleanup function and dependencies. Also include the `useState` that `setText` is presumably coming from

Comment: And add the [tag:reactjs] tag while you're at it, please.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same problem as JS used to have here, *(before the introduction of `let` and `const`)*

```js
for (var i=0; i<5; ++i) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 10);
}
```

by the time `console.log(i)` is executed by setTimeout, the loop has already progressed `++i` to the end of the loop.

Same happens in your code, by the time `prevText + message[initialIndex]` is called, the next iteration of `setinterval` has already been called and executed another `initialIndex++;`

This happens because `setText` is async and React decides when to execute the callback function. And if there is enough load React may delay that call.

To fix this you need a locally scoped variable that stores the index just for this one iterations:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let message = 'This is not working';
  let index = 0;
  setText('');

  const typingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (index < message.length) {
      const char = message[index++]; // this part runs immediately
      setText(text => text + char);  // this, when React is in the mood for it.
    } else {
      clearInterval(typingInterval);
    }
  }, 100);
  
  return () => clearInterval(typingInterval);
}, []);
```

> It works if I prepend two spaces at the beginning of the string, but I have no idea why.

this is purely by chance, the same as the error itself. This "solution" may or may not work depending on if/how React decides to delay the execution of the callback passed to `setTimeout`.

Bergis comment:

> Instead of `const char = message[index++]`, just do `const char = message[text.length]` inside the callback

just to clarify this, this would look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let message = 'This is not working';
  let index = 0;
  setText('');

  const typingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (index < message.length) {
      setText(text => text + message[text.length]);
    } else {
      clearInterval(typingInterval);
    }
  }, 100);
  
  return () => clearInterval(typingInterval);
}, []);
```

---

Actually, you don't need to attach the message char by char:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let message = 'This is not working';
  let index = 0;
  setText('');

  const typingInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if (index < message.length) {
      setText(message.slice(0, ++index));
    } else {
      clearInterval(typingInterval);
    }
  }, 100);
  
  return () => clearInterval(typingInterval);
}, []);
```

Comment: Instead of `const char = message[index++]`, just do `const char = message[text.length]` inside the callback

Answer (score 0):

`setState` method is asynchronous, so `initialIndex++` runs before your `setText` and it skips the index number 0.

**Solution**

https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback#usage

Comment: Thank you, is there a solution to this?

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687091/can-i-execute-a-function-after-setstate-is-finished-updating

Comment: I moved it after the `else` clause and it's still not working. Thanks for the link I'll check it out

Comment: `setText` vs `setState`?

Comment: Please include the solution in your answer instead of just linking to it